# Munit test case getting InterceptionException error

Tags: mule, munit

I am getting InterceptionException while executing a munit test case. The Munit version I am using is 2.1.5. Below is the error stack trace I am getting.

```
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.InterceptionException: 
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveInterceptionAction.failWithMessage(ReactiveInterceptionAction.java:100)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveInterceptionAction.fail(ReactiveInterceptionAction.java:113)
    at org.mule.munit.mock.interception.MunitProcessorInterceptor.failProcessor(MunitProcessorInterceptor.java:170)
    at org.mule.munit.mock.interception.MunitProcessorInterceptor.around(MunitProcessorInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.lambda$doAround$3(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:94)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.doAround(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:93)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.lambda$null$1(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:60)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:350)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust$WeakScalarSubscription.request(FluxJust.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:335)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90)
    at ...
    at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain$1.onNext(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:285)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:204)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnValue$ScheduledScalar.run(FluxSubscribeOnValue.java:178)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:50)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:111)
    at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here I am mocking timeout error for IBM MQ here with error type `IBM-MQ:TIMEOUT` and passing header values in a transform message and asserting with `expression="#[payload]" is="#[MunitTools::notNullValue()]`. Any help! I want to know why and how this error is coming, as I could not find any particular issue while debugging the test case.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the expectedErrorType attribute on the MUnit test:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/2.2/test-mock-errors-cookbook#on-error-propagate

Answer (score 0):

If you set an error type in the mock, it will throw an exception with that error type. In this case, the exception is InterceptionException, associated with the provided error type

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I mentioned in the description, I am mocking timeout error by setting error type `IBM-MQ:TIMEOUT` here. The error stack trace which I have mentioned is munit execution error which I have got while executing the munit test suite. I am getting the same error for  `IBM-MQ:CONNECTIVITY` also when I try to mock MQ connectivity error. I want to know why I am getting this error and what causes this.

Answer (score 0):

With IBM MQ i will recommend at least to get a live test environment with IBM-MQ. cause it never runs as expected.